# C# Visual Studio Chart need help to make yAxis start from another point

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts

does anyone know if there is a way to make the SplineRange in Chart for visual studio Start at 3 instead of 0?

i am trying to get the YAxis to start from 3 and not 0

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9MXE.png)

i want it to look like this

[From 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GfgP.png)

how do i remove that extra color filling that happens ? i tried

```
UpChart_Chart.ChartAreas.FindByName("UpChart").AxisY.Crossing = 3;
            UpChart_Chart.ChartAreas.FindByName("UpChart").AxisY.IntervalOffset = 3;
```

Comment: did not work it still fills the entier bottom out with color.

Comment: Actually all you need is to set the AxisY.Minimum = 3

Comment: doesnt work i need it to show 0 but start from 3 and use that as bottom line since i need to put in multiple graphs on same chart

Comment: So you don't  to _make yAxis start from another point_ but blank out a part in a chart. I don't think this is possible. You may try overlaying the lower part with a white block but it may interfere with the other series..

Comment: it should be possible since when u put in default chart it shows it can so

Comment: You can try to read what the designer.cs has..